# Call function from hyperlink defined in qTip content

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip

I am trying to call a javascript function from a hyperlink that is part of the content in a qTip. I keep getting the error my function is not defined but it is defined within the page and can be called outside of qTip. Below is what I have so far:

```
    function addCalendarToolTip(objTarget, objEvent) {
        $(objTarget).qtip({
            content: '<a href="#" onClick="tester();">mylink</a>' });
```

function tester() { alert("hello world"); }

If I put the alert within the onClick attribute, I at least get the alert to work. Is there some special way of calling a function from within qTip? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is this function inside your `document.ready`?

Comment: yes, the code in the post all resides in document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working for me now. Not sure what I was doing wrong to begin with :P